# git permissions not working in azure devops

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, devops, branch

I want to deny anyone in the team to refrain from creating a branch based on the main branch in Azure Devops. I am using git repos. Though I execute the below command(and it runs successfully) it doesn't work. Still I am able to create a branch based out of main. I belong to the contributor and project administrator group as well.

```
tf git permission /deny:CreateBranch /group:[scrum]\Contributors /collection:https://dev.azure.com/00000/ /teamproject:scrum /repository:dev /branch:main
```

Comment: *How* are you creating the branch? Via the UI or the Git CLI? Because it's not going to stop you from running local Git commands.

Comment: creating the branch through UI only